# Loop through $_POST values

Tags: php

I have a very simple form on my website.

I run this **PHP** to loop the form contents:

```
echo '<pre>';
var_dump($_POST);
echo '</pre>';

$i = 0;

foreach($_POST as $key => $value)
{

    $i++;
    echo $value[$i]['row_id'];

}
```

I get the below:

```
array(1) {
  ["data"]=> array(2) {
            [1]=>  array(2) {
                ["row_id"]=> string(5) "33714"
                ["sport"]=> string(8) "swimming"
            }
            [2]=> array(2) {
                ["row_id"]=> string(5) "33715"
                ["sport"]=> string(8) "football"
            }
  }
}

33714
```

My PHP only echoes the first row id `33714` instead of both rows.

I feel I'm missing something obvious here.

Comment: @brombeer Even then it still just seems to loop one row.

Comment: Your records are in the `data` key

Comment: **That code, does not generate that output from that input** ???? It generates `33715`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply put, you need to loop the items of `$_POST['data']` instead of just `$_POST`

```php
echo '<pre>';
var_dump($_POST);
echo '</pre>';

foreach($_POST['data'] as $key => $item)
{
    echo $key.':'. $item['row_id'];

}
```

Comment: Amazing. That works beautifully. Thank you so much for taking the time.

Answer (score 3):

You're looping over the wrong thing **and** you're simultaneously using two different methods to loop over the same thing.

1. You set `$i` to `0`
2. Your `foreach` loop reaches `$_POST['data']`
3. You change `$i` to `1`
4. You access `$_POST['data'][1]`
5. You get to the end of the loop

You need to loop over what you actually want to loop over.

`data` is a fixed thing, so hard code that. Then loop over the array it contains.

Only use a `$i` variable if you are using a [regular `for` loop](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php).

When you use `foreach` you use the variable(s) you define inside it (in this case `$key` and `$value`).

```
foreach($_POST['data'] as $key => $value) {
    echo $value['row_id']
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for putting this together. Bit rusty with PHP so greatly appreciate the help.